# How can I write a function to handle any command matching a regular expression?

Tags: bash

If I have the regular expression `^[A-X]+\.+[0-4]+$`.

How can I call a function defined in my .profile whenever I type a matching string into the command line?

Comment: The profile doesn't run while you're executing commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this in `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.profile`, on operating systems that don't mess with bash's startup behavior. That said, a `command_not_found_handle` function is a mechanism to implement this kind of logic:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if [[ $1 =~ ^[A-X]+\.+[0-4]+$ ]]; then
    call_your_function "$@"
  else
    printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
    return 127  # standard command-not-found return value
  fi
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.